# Featured Image metabox lost

Tags: images, taxonomy

I can't get the Featured Image metabox and taxonomy to show up on the edit page for the default post and page post types.
it does work for the custom post type I've created using a plugin. It just doesn't work with the default ones.

Also been checking the screen options on the top right of the edit page and the checkbox for the Featured Image is not even there.

i have desactivated all my pluging + with basic theme and the featured image option doesn t show up

Problem since i upgraded 3 weeks ago on wp 4.3.1

My Html code is

```
<div style="" id="postimagediv" class="postbox  hide-if-js">
```

if i put 
`<div style="display: block;" id="postimagediv" class="postbox  hide-if-js">`

My features image is display and i can post correctly, where can i set this value by defaut without adding the html code with firebug?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the following in your functions.php file - it might solve the problem:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Answer (score -1):

No it not do anything, the only way i can get the featured images is by editing the code into firebug adding style="display: block;

and i do not see the post content, with add media and field for the text =/